# Can ::first-letter CSS work on <text> elements in SVGs?

Tags: css, svg

As far as I can tell, the CSS3 `::first-child` pseudo-element selector does not work on text inside SVGs.

My attempt is in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tobek/d334vdb5/, which doesn't work for me on latest Chrome and Firefox (on Linux). Here's the full code:

HTML:

```html
<div class="html-text">Watermelon</div>

<svg width="400" height="50">
  <text x="0" y="50" font-size="50">Watermelon</text>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```css
.html-text {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: green;
}
.html-text::first-letter {
  color: red;
}

svg text {
  fill: green;
}
svg text::first-letter {
  fill: red;
  color: red;
}
```

This produces:

[image]

Searched for specific info on this but couldn't find any. If it is in fact not possible, is there some more general rule about what CSS does not work on text elements in SVGs?

Comment: This might help you: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-and-css.html and especially http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/text-element.html

Comment: Thanks, just read through them both but no clear answer. The second link has a list of "text-specific CSS properties you can use to style text", but some properties that aren't on that list (like `text-shadow`) *do* seem to work reliably, so I don't know what the "ultimate" list of permissible properties is and/or if there's some hack to make it kind of work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [specs for SVG 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#StylingWithCSS) <sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

> CSS2's dynamic pseudo-classes :hover, :active and :focus and pseudo-classes :first-child, :visited, :link and :lang ([CSS2], section 5.11). **The remaining CSS2 pseudo-classes**, including those having to do with generated content ([CSS2], chapter 12), **are not part of the SVG language definition.**

So nope, `::first-letter` should not work on svg.

Note that you could workaround it by using `<tspan>` elements and the `:first-child` selector though.

```css
.html-text {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: green;
}
.html-text::first-letter {
  color: red;
}

svg text {
  fill: green;
}
svg text :first-child {
  fill: red;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="html-text">Watermelon</div>

<svg width="400" height="50">
  <text x="0" y="50" font-size="50"><tspan>W</tspan>atermelon</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Excellent answer, with a well-anticipated alternative solution. Thanks.